# Where is the transparency and mirror setting in blender 2.9?

Tags: animation, materials, filmic-blender

[image]

Alright guys I am trying to find transparency and mirror setting in blender 2.9 in the materials
properties however it is not there, is there a transparency and mirror setting in 2.9 ?

The screenshot is from blender 2.79

Thanks

Comment: What are you producing this for, you making a glass box? etc... The number of bounces for a light ray has through a transparent object is defined by the number of transparent bounces in the light paths section of the Cycles rendering area, whilst the transparency of a material is set via the alpha within the material editor of the principled shader. However there are better ways to produce a glass like effect in blender, as such a little more clarity would be appreciated

Comment: Yes I am trying to make a glass box.

Comment: Okay see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I've tried to recreate what you wanted, hopefully it is passable in the short space of time that I made it. It consists of 2 point lights with edited radius'. The boxes are subdivided once in the editor. Then I added thickness with a solidification modifier, bevelled the edges with bevel modifier and subdivided a few times with a subdivision modifier using catmull-clark smoothing. You can see the material node set up I used for the glass, as well as the render properties. I am using a denoiser at a fairly low level of samples, which is why it's a bit blurred.

Other than that it's just sitting on a standard subdivided plain with an extruded corner which I bevelled, with an AO node in the material set up and you're golden.

Here's the wireframe:
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks, can the settings be used to make something like this ?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PsuBbxXXSFH5zN1nRrsMOiuuXF7an_Ty/view?usp=sharing

and 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYEVUHnT1MU

Comment: You could make something close, but the lighting and the refraction are different

Comment: Thanks, I am new to this but would like to make something like the youtube link I have provided, or something very close to it. If you are a blender designer would you by any chance be able to construct one like the youtube video and I am more than happy to buy that 3d model from you. You see me trying to figure out how the light polarization and refraction works may take extreme long amount of time, so just wondering if you would be able to replicate such a cube.  Thanks

Comment: Absolutely not, this is a site for learning, not for bartering

Comment: No problem, thanks.